# Calling asynchronous method of an interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous

I have a class which is dependent on a small interface with a method which is asynchronous due to it being slow. Please look at the following code:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace eFoo
{
    public interface IFooService
    {
        Task<double> GetFooAmount(int fooId);
    }

    public class FooInfo
    {
        private readonly int _fooId;
        private readonly IFooService _fooService;
        public FooInfo(int fooId, IFooService fooService)
        {
            _fooId = fooId;
            _fooService = fooService;
        }
        public double Amount { get; private set; }
        public async Task RefreshAmount()
        {
            Amount = _fooService.GetFooAmount(_fooId);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

now I'm having problem with public async Task RefreshAmount()
receiving following compilation error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'double'

Did I made the wrong approach to make the method in the interface to return Task? and if not, how can I solve the error message? 
Update:
Also I like to know how could I have the RefreshAmount method unit tested now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much like you cannot assign a `string` to a `int` you cannot assign a `Task<double>` to a `double`.

A `Task<T>` represents the asynchronous operation and not the result itself. To obtain the result you can `await` the result like this:

```
Amount = await _fooService.GetFooAmount(_fooId);
```

Optionally, you could obtain the result *synchronously* by means of the `Result` property:

```
Amount = _fooService.GetFooAmount(_fooId).Result;
```

Comment: Thanks! May I also know if you'd think I took the right approach for making the call to GetFooAmount, more reliable?

Comment: @Elham That would depend on the implementation of `GetFooAmount`.